# Google reCaptcha verify not perfect display on iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, recaptcha

I am trying to display Google reCaptcha on iframe but problem is google verify display on scroll not fully display.

[image]

Here I faced scrollbar in popup form when google reCaptcha does not verify.
How can I set auto height of iframe in popup form ?

My iframe code

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="localhost/nitin/test1/" style="border: none;height: 100px !important;margin: 0px !important;width: 300px !important;"></iframe>
```

My page code in create google reCaptcha

```
<div style="width:230px; overflow:hidden"> 
    <div data-callback="enableBtn" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld6txMTAAAAAEN10JIKnj2jZAOUYJdy‌​p1DjG9Y1" style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform‌​:scale(0.77);transfo‌​rm-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;"> </div> 
</div>
```

I am not use any plugin this is my own code.

Comment: Maybe post some code so we can see how you installed it?

Comment: =>my iframe code

<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="localhost/nitin/test1/"  style="border: none;height: 100px !important;margin: 0px !important;width: 300px !important;"></iframe>

=>my page code in create google reCaptcha

<div style="width:230px; overflow:hidden">    <div data-callback="enableBtn" class="g-recaptcha"                data-sitekey="6Ld6txMTAAAAAEN10JIKnj2jZAOUYJdyp1DjG9Y1"                style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;">
    </div>
</div>
i am not use any plugin this is my own code.

Comment: Please delete that comment and add the code in the OP with the proper formatting. I can't read it like that.

Comment: Remove your `height: 100px` and `width: 300px` from your iframe code and remove `width:230px;` from reCaptcha

Comment: i already remove height and width still not display in full screen.

Comment: Try removing those `transform:scale(0.77)` and `-webkit-transform‌​:scale(0.77)`